# Note taking app with consolidated todo list

Tags: note-taking

I know a number of note apps can embed todo items, but none that I have found provide a consolidated view of all outstanding todos across all notes.

I talk to a lot of customers every week and I’d like to keep a separate folder or tag for each of them with multiple notes. I want an easy way to mark something as an action item that I need to follow up on inline within the note app itself and then have a mater view where I can see all my action items across all notes.

Ideally I’d need something that runs locally on my Mac and at least has an option not to sync data to any remote services, but if there is a Windows only or web-based app that has this feature, I’d like to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a main feature of [Org](http://orgmode.org). You can mark any note anywhere in a set of files as a TODO item, then use an [agenda view](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Views.html#Agenda-Views) to see all your TODO items at once, optionally grouped by date if you've given them dates.

Org is a package for Emacs, which runs on Mac OS. It doesn't communicate with the Internet by default, although you can opt into various synchronization features.